# Center header elements

Tags: html, css, center

I'm having trouble with center the elements both vertically and horizontally in the header. Can anyone help me please? Here are my HTML and CSS codes:

`

```
<header>
    <a href="#my_photo" class="logo header_element"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="100" height="100"></a> <!--link to homepage-->
    <nav class="navigation">
        <a class="header_element" href="#professional">PROFESSIONAL</a>
        <a class="header_element" href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a>
        <a class="header_element" href="#portfolio">PORTFOLIO</a>
        <a class="header_element" href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

`

`

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    background: #172135;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
} 

#logo {
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 4.5%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
}
.navigation {
    position: relative;
    top: -25px;
    word-spacing: 3.5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

`

The code above works normal for full size window.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyLoY.jpg)

But when I change the window size. The elements are not in center anymore.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmCHB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of height of navigation class

if you add height:100px to navigation class will do what you want

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work

Comment: so if it's possible make codesandbox for it, I can fix it